# copy entire folder contents - not just the outputted file

Tags: find, rsync

I would like to use `find` and `rsync` to copy any directory that contains at least one "wav" file.  The copying should copy the whole folder if a "wav" file is present.  I have this so far:

```
find . -name "*.wav" | rsync -armR --include="*/" --include="*.wav" --exclude="*" /users/lukew/desktop/merged /users/lukew/desktop/123;
```

This is good because the output is distributed into the correct directory at the output level as a single "wav" file. I'd also like the other files in the source directory to be included at the same time to go alongside the "wav" file in the output directory.

Comment: Your command doesn't make sense as `rsync` is doing nothing with the list of files generated by `find`. What do you actually want to achieve (preferably with examples)?

Comment: Please don't leave all these comments here. Comments are easy to miss and hard to read and they can be deleted without warning. All relevant details need to be in the body of your question, so please [edit] and add them. Explain i) what you want to do; ii) what is actually happening.

Comment: @LukeW Move all relevant comments into the text of the question (and remove them as comments). I would also be happy if you could include a listing of some part of the directory hierarchy that you are copying from, including file names. My solution works for me and at least one other person, and I think there's something up with the way the source directory is organised.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what directories include `.wav` files:

```
find . -type d \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*.wav; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} ';' \
    -print
```

This goes through all directories under `.` and tries the glob pattern `*.wav` in all of them. If the pattern is unexpanded, then we assume that there is no `.wav` file there (this will fail if there is a file with the literal name `*.wav` in a directory and no other `.wav` files in the same directory).

Then we may incorporate `rsync` into the above command to sync these directories:

```
find . -type d \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*.wav; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} ';' \
    -exec rsync -a {} /path/to/destination/ ';'
```

This will create a subdirectory under `/path/to/destination` for each directory found to contain a `.wav` file.

Testing:

```
$ tree Source
Source
|-- A
|   |-- a.wav
|   |-- hs.doc
|   `-- hy.xls
|-- B
|   |-- hs.doc
|   `-- py.xls
`-- C
    |-- CA
    |   |-- d.wav
    |   |-- h.doc
    |   `-- h.xls
    `-- CB
        |-- h.doc
        `-- hd.xls

5 directories, 10 files
```

Running the command:

```
$ find Source -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*.wav; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} ';' -exec rsync -a {} Dest/ ';'
```

Checking the result:

```
$ tree Dest
Dest
|-- A
|   |-- a.wav
|   |-- hs.doc
|   `-- hy.xls
`-- CA
    |-- d.wav
    |-- h.doc
    `-- h.xls

2 directories, 6 files
```

The `Dest` directory was already existing, but empty.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66087/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-copy-entire-folder-contents-not-just-the-o).

Comment: Should I paste into terminal: 
$ find Source -type d \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*.mobi; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} ';' \
    -exec rsync -a {} users/lukew/desktop/123dest/ ';'

Question : should steps be implemented before this?
If I include the $ at the beginning of find it says -bash: $: command not found. I removed the $ and began it with find. Then it says sh: -c: line1:syntax error: unexpected end of file sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `" '

Comment: @LukeW The `$` is the primary prompt shown by the shell (you don't type this, it's just showing that the command is typed at an interactive shell prompt). You should press return directly after each backslash, or write the whole command on one lang line (I have done that in the updated answer).

Comment: Yes that seems to work except how do I maintain the original directory structure, recursive option is that?

Comment: @LukeW The `-a` option for `rsync` includes the `-r` option for recursive copy. Remember, it's only the directories that contain a particular file type that is copied (as per the question), parent directories are ignored.

Comment: What is confusing me is that with a smaller source things work and yet when I try a greater source size that folders are copied that don't include wav which does not make sense at all. The solution you've made provides good output except the directories do not tell me what their parents were so output is not as meaningful as it could be

Comment: I made rsync -a become rsync -armR and this fixed the directory structure to how I like it. The large sample size though continues to replicate the non wav file containing directory being copied still

Comment: The larger source sample has more subdirectories. I'm thinking this may contribute to non wave directories being copied

Comment: I've worked out what's causing output problems is when there is a wav file in the same directory as the source files. If the source files are all folders there is no issue it would seem. It would be good though if we could solve this because it could lead to consequential issues. Cheers

Comment: This is where it's at
find /users/lukew/desktop/input -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1”/*.wav; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} ';' -exec rsync -armRg {} /users/lukew/desktop/output ';'

It would be great if this could be changed so that if there's a directory which contains a wav file that folders which do not include a wav file are not outputted

Comment: $ tree Source
Source
|-- A
|   |-- a.wav
|   |-- hs.doc
|   `-- hy.xls
|-- B
|   |-- hs.doc
|   `-- py.xls
`-- C
    |-- CA
    |   |-- d.wav
    |   |-- h.doc
    |   `-- h.xls
    `-- CB
        |-- h.doc
        `-- hd.xls

If we apply it against the above what happens is that CB won’t be output as designed. However if directory C has a wav file in it then it will be output and we don’t want that

Comment: So CB will be output if C contains .wav file which is not how we want it. We want CB to not be outputted regardless of C or the like containing a .wav file and we want this methodology to apply globally to every directory so that an errant .wav doesn't create folders being output that don't contain wav. It's only .wav files creating this problem